# Could NOT find Qt6Quick (missing: Qt6Quick_DIR)

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, qt-quick, qt6

The following code works:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Quick)
```

It results in an error:

```
-- Could NOT find Qt6Quick (missing: Qt6Quick_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find Qt component "Quick".

  Expected Config file at
  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6Quick/Qt6QuickConfig.cmake" does NOT
  exist
```

The system has the packages `qt6-base-dev`, `qt6-base-dev-tools`, and `qt6-qmltooling-plugins` installed.
Maybe there are some additional packages required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of `qt6-declarative-dev` solved the issue.

Additionally, for anyone planning to use `Qt Quick`, it would be helpful to install the packages `qml6-module-qtqml`, `qml6-module-qtquick`, `qml6-module-qtquick-controls`, `qml6-module-qtquick-dialogs`, `qml6-module-qtquick-window`, `qml6-module-qtquick-layouts`, `qml6-module-qtcore`.